# What should be the input for following functions in web3js?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

web3 js functions like:

`getTransaction()` What should be the input? contract address or account address or transaction hash?

likewise for other contracts like `getTransactionReceipt` and all?

Comment: It is a good practice that accepting the answer as correct if it helped you resolved the issue. That is the whole point of SE none of the answers for your questions are marked as correct. FYI, if youre not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs,

> web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash [, callback])

**Returns a transaction matching the given transaction hash.**

Parameters

1. String - The transaction hash.
2. Function - (optional) If you pass a callback the HTTP request is made asynchronous. See this note for details.

### [web3.ETH.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) will return `The 32 Bytes transaction hash as HEX string.`